# Attribute options import in magento 2

Tags: attributes, attribute-options, magento-2.2.5

I have added additional colomns description and image  in eav_attribute_option_value table.

Which means each option of an custom attribute has its own description and image.

I have saved the attribute options for an attribute, but failed to save options's image and description please provide me a solution.

```
function getAddOptions($objectManager, $option, $attributeName)
{
    $eavConfig = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Eav\Model\Config');
    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attributeName);
    $status = checkExistingOptions($option, $eavConfig, $attribute);
    if (!$status) {
        $newOption['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getAttributeId();


        $newOption['value'][0][0] = $option;
        $newOption['description'][0][0] = 'nice color';

        $eavSetup = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup');
        $eavSetup->addAttributeOption($newOption);
        // $eavSetup->addAttributeDescription($descArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: add code what you have tried so far

Comment: It saves only the option but failed to save the description